# taylor expansion of function with a vector as variable

Tags: taylor-expansion

I know how to do a taylor expansion of a function from R to R. I dont know how to do taylor expansion of functions which have 3D vectors as variable. How can I do this? I would appreciate it if someone also worked out an example. Thank you!

Comment: The title says "vector valued" and your question mentions "vectors as variable", which is it ?

Comment: @JoelCohen sorry for the confusion, I am not good at the terminology. I meant a function which has a vector as a variable

Comment: Do you have an example in mind?

Comment: @Muphrid f(x)=|a-x|^3 for example with x and a 3D vector and the vertical lines mean the length (here a is constant).

Comment: So $x$ and $a$ are both vectors, just $a$ is a constant vector?

Comment: @Muphrid exactly, x is the variable

Comment: Wiki source - look for scalar-valued function with a vector variable... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_in_several_variables

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Then what you're looking for is the Taylor expansion of a scalar field--a function $f$ that maps $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$.

An easy way to build up intuition about this is to do the expansion only in one direction.  Let $e_i$ be an element of a basis $\lbrace e_1,\dots, e_n \rbrace$ of $\mathbb R^n$ and $t$ a scalar parameter.  Let $x_0$, the point you want to expand around, be given by $x_0 = x - t e_i$ or $x = x_0 + t e_i$.  There is only one direction connecting $x$ and $x_0$, and the magnitude can always be calculated (which fixes $t$).  Then you can say

$$
f(x) = f(x_0) + Df(x_0)(te_i) + \frac{1}{2}D^2f(x_0)(te_i,te_i) + o(t^2)\,,
$$
namely
$$f(x) = f(x_0 + t e_i) = f(x_0) + \left. \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \right|_{x_0} t + \frac{1}{2} \left. \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i^2} \right|_{x_0} t^2 + o(t^2)\,.$$

Now, identify $\partial f/\partial x_i$ as $e_i \cdot \nabla f$.  In addition, see that $t e_i = x - x_0$.  Some clever recombining of terms gives

$$f(x) = f(x_0) + (x-x_0) \cdot \nabla f|_{x_0} + \frac{1}{2} ((x - x_0) \cdot \nabla)^2 f|_{x_0} + o(t^2)\,.$$

This is suitably general to cover any point $x$.

Comment: I dont understand why f(x)=f(x_0 +tn). could you explain? and what does de upside down delta f mean?

Comment: I've added some additional language to clarify why $x = x_0 + t \hat n$.  The symbol $\nabla$ (pronounced *del*) represents the vector derivative operator.  Acting on a scalar field, it produces the gradient.

Comment: @Muphrid How does the second-order term $t^2\partial_{tt}$ become $(x-x_0)\cdot \nabla)^2$?

Comment: @BillyJean: $([x-x_0] \cdot \nabla)^2 = t^2 (\hat n \cdot \nabla)^2 = t^2 \partial_{tt}$.  Remember I said to identify $\hat n \cdot \nabla = \partial_t$.